# How to have heading above login table

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am creating a login page with username and password. I want to put a text heading "Login App" at he top left side of the login panel table. I tried using panel tag but didn't work. You know there is a heading above the login panel or login table on almost any login page? I just want to do that.

Is there a really simple and easy way/tag i can use to do this? I even tried placeholder but couldn't achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: can't you just put the <h1> tag above the login table?

Comment: also, link a jsfiddle with your code in it, and we will edit it to be correct

Comment: @SamDenton i tried to use h1 tag but then there was padding issue and i am not that much used to with css so still getting it practiced. And thanks for jsfiddle suggestion, will use it henceforth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to have heading to login table is

**fieldset and legend**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
fieldset {position: relative; width:50%}
legend {color:#893039 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">Login App:</legend>
<table>  
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

working sample is given in jsfiddle in this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/Manirajss/QKeHq/

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for! the fieldset tag seems to be the perfect tag for this!

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the following design and put it in aspx

```
<h2>
    Log In
</h2>
<p>
    Please enter your username and password.
    <asp:HyperLink ID="RegisterHyperLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">Register</asp:HyperLink> if you don't have an account.
</p>
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <span class="failureNotification">
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </span>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
        <div class="accountInfo">
            <fieldset class="login">
                <legend>Account Information</legend>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <p class="submitButton">
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```